# Some tests to see whether the code generated for iteration using pointers and iteration using indexing is different?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Is there a way to check if the compiler generates equivalent code for iteration using pointers and iteration using indexing???
i.e. for the codes

```
  void f1(char v[])
  {
       for(int i=0; v[i]!=0;i++) use(v[i]);
  }
```

and

```
 void f1(char v[])
  {
       for(char *p = v; *p!=0; p++) use(*p);
  }
```

I use microsoft visual C++ as my compiler......

Please help.....

Comment: v[i]!=0 and *p!=0  may cause Undefined behavior. Use length of array to check the end to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a breakpoint in the function.
2. Verify that you compile in Release (otherwise it will surely be different) with debug information turned on.
3. Run.
4. Open the Assembly window to see the generated assembly (usually Alt+8).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Visual Studio in some time, but I think there should be an option to create assembler files that you could compare.

Otherwise you can have two C files, one with each version of the function, and create object files from them. Then use a disassembler to get the assembler code, and compare the two files.